# Is it just me? I find LINQ to XML to be sort of cumbersome, compared to XPath

Tags: .net, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I am a C# programmer, so I don't get to take advantage of the cool XML syntax in VB.

```
Dim itemList1 = From item In rss.<rss>.<channel>.<item> _
                Where item.<description>.Value.Contains("LINQ") Or _
                      item.<title>.Value.Contains("LINQ")
```

Using C#, I find [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to be easier to think about, easier to code, easier to understand, than performing a multi-nested select using [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML).  Look at this syntax, it looks like Greek swearing:

```
var waypoints = from waypoint in gpxDoc.Descendants(gpx + "wpt") 
          select new 
          { 
            Latitude = waypoint.Attribute("lat").Value, 
            Longitude = waypoint.Attribute("lon").Value, 
            Elevation = waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele") != null ? 
                waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele").Value : null, 
            Name = waypoint.Element(gpx + "name") != null ? 
                waypoint.Element(gpx + "name").Value : null, 
            Dt = waypoint.Element(gpx + "cmt") != null ? 
                waypoint.Element(gpx + "cmt").Value : null 
          };
```

All the casting, the heavy syntax, the possibility for NullPointerExceptions.  None of this happens with XPath.

I like LINQ in general, and I use it on object collections and databases, but my first go-round with querying XML led me right back to XPath.

Is it just me?

Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**: someone voted to close this as "not a real question".  But it *is* a real question, stated clearly.  The question is: *Am I misunderstanding 
something with LINQ to XML?*

Comment: I agree, I love L2O, L2S etc but when dealing with xml I just fall back to using xpath together with xmldocument/xmlnode/xmlelement etc. Linq-to-XML is maybe easier to get started with but if you have xpath in your fingers then it won't beat xpath...

Comment: No, it's not just you. Linq-to-XML might seem like a "smarter" approach, but like you, I still prefer XPath. If you know XPath and can make use of it - by all means, do so! :-) You're not alone :-)

Comment: It's not really surprising that something that is new to you seems less obvious than something you know already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use what you feel the most comfortable with, as long as it gets the job done.  I use both methods depending on what I need to do to with XML.  It sounds to me like you've got a good handle on what LINQ is good for and what XPath is good for.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the example you've given is unweildy.

But with LINQ comes the flexibility to refactor away the unweildiness.

Here's an example of how I would improve it. (This is done without any testing at all, and I don't even know the real class names, but it should convey the idea)

```
static class LinqXmlExtension
{
    public static NodeThingy ElementOrNull(this XmlElement ele, string searchString)
    {
         return (ele.Element(searchString) != null ? ele.Element(searchString).Value : null);
    }
}

//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var waypoints = from waypoint in gpxDoc.Descendants(gpx + "wpt")           
                select new           
                {             
                      Latitude  = waypoint.Attribute("lat").Value,             
                      Longitude = waypoint.Attribute("lon").Value,
                      Elevation = waypoint.ElementOrNull(gpx + "ele"),
                      Name      = waypoint.ElementOrNull(gpx + "name"),
                      Dt        = waypoint.ElementOrNull(gpx + "cmt")           
                 };
```

Comment: It is still much more cumbersome than an elegant XPath expression.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'd love to see your elegant xpath expression that returns the above collection.

Comment: @TimJarvis: I'd like to provide one -- could you, please, specify the XML document and what exactly nodes should be selected? These aren't provided in the above answer, which make it even more hanging in the air.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing at some of your data types, but you could make your C# LINQ query concise by casting your attribute values:

```
var waypoints =
    from waypoint in gpxDoc.Descendants(gpx + "wpt") 
    select new 
    { 
        Latitude = (decimal)waypoint.Attribute("lat"), 
        Longitude = (decimal)waypoint.Attribute("lon"), 
        Elevation = (decimal?)waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele"), 
        Name = (string)waypoint.Element(gpx + "name"), 
        Dt = (DateTime?)waypoint.Element(gpx + "cmt")
    };
```

And I'm sure you already know the @ syntax you can use for attributes in VB's XML literals.

Comment: It is still much more cumbersome than an elegant XPath expression

Comment: It's been a little while since I've dealt with straight XPath (and not using it with Linq to Xml), but an example of the 'simpler' XPath expression would be great. Personally, I think this example looks great, and it's how I normally do things.

Comment: @Ryan-Versaw I'd love to provide an XPath expression (be it XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0), if there is a specific XML document provided and if there is a strict description of what result must be produced.

Answer (score 1):

I can see your problem but I used LINQ for just reorder a GPX file to get trackpoints in every segment in the correct order and it feels rather straight forward.....

```
       var trksegs = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "trkseg");
        foreach (var trkseg in trksegs)
        {
            List<XElement> trk = trkseg.Elements(ns + "trkpt")
                 .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "time")).ToList();
            trkseg.RemoveAll();
            trkseg.Add(trk);
        }
```

and also fix a bug in a delivered GPX file for time

```
  private static XDocument ConvertTimeElement(XDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc.Root != null)
        {
            var times = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "time").ToList();
            foreach (var time in times)
                time.SetValue((string)ConvertSpotDateFormat(time));
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

I think it is rather straight format....

(The problem I fixed http://www.everytrail.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1980&p=6447#p6447)